# use argument to system object in matlab code generation

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, codegen

I'm tring to use system object for my generated matlab code (.mex)

here is the function.

```
function [  ] = filereaderTest( videofile )

fileReader = vision.VideoFileReader(videofile);

while ~isDone(fileReader)
    step(fileReader);
    % do something
end

release(fileReader);

end
```

when I try codegen filereaderTest -args videofile , error occurs.
It says "fail to compute constant value for constructor arguement #1. To generate code, all argument for System Object constructor should be constant. ..."

To use VideoFileReader, must pass file name to its constructor.
So, here is my question: there is any way to use this function to any files? for example:

```
filereaderTest.mex(video1);
filereaderTest.mex(video2); % video1 and video2 are different
```

Comment: As @Daniel says you cannot change videofile after compilation. You need two objects if you have two video files and inline the name of the files. Also you would not get much speed if you are compiling only the video file readers since they involve file read operations. You are better off directly using the objects in MATLAB instead of mex files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible. The documentation states clearly:

> Set arguments to System object™ constructors as compile-time constants.
>   [(1)](http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/gs/use-system-objects-in-matlab-code-generation.html)